# Bash find using regex fails with digit matching

Tags: linux, bash, regex, find

I'm using `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0` with `GNU bash, version 5.0.17`.

```bash
touch hello.32.world.txt
find . # works, output is: ./hello.32.world.txt
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*hello\.32\.world\.txt'     # works
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*hello\.[0-9]+\.world\.txt' # works
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*hello\.\d+\.world\.txt'    # fails
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*hello\.[\d]+\.world\.txt'  # fails
```

Am I missing some kind of escape sequence to make `\d+` match one or more digits?

If I type `find -regextype help`, it says `valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’`. Trying those did not work either.

Comment: POSIX EREs are specified [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04). I think there is no `\d` in the specification.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks, at least I know I'm not crazy now and blundering a character escape. You're right, I think only Perl-style 'PCRE' regexes have that, and all of the regex variants I'm used to in programming languages are based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `d+` won’t work in a case like this. In this case, try using `[[:digit:]]` instead like this:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*hello\.[[:digit:]]+\.world\.txt'
```

Or use `[0-9]{1,2}` to match a specific number of digits; in this case 1 to 2 digits:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*hello\.[0-9]{1,2}\.world\.txt'
```